# Entity framework and datetime compare

Tags: linq, entity-framework, datetime, entity-framework-4

Is possible to create linq query to find all records, which are in date range?

For example :

I have table with VacationStart, VacationEnd - both datetime and i need find all pending vacations to current date.

I am trying

```
 context.Vacations..Where(x=> x.VacationStart >= DateTime.Now && x.VacationEnd < DateTime.Now)
```

but i getting 0 records...

Sample data 2011-10-27 08:30:00.000  2011-10-28 17:00:00.000

Current date : 2011-10-26 23:39:46.297

Where i do mistake?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking for vacations that start after NOW and end before NOW, Impossible. try asking and comparing a start time and end time that are different and where start time is less than the end time.

Gives only the vacations currently in progress.

```
var query = context.Vacations.Where(v => v.VacationEnd > DateTime.Now 
   && v.VacationStart < DateTime.Now);
```

Gives vacations that haven not begun yet.

```
var query = context.Vacations.Where(v => v.VacationStart > DateTime.Now);
```

Gives Vacations that are in progress or still have not started.

```
var query = context.Vacations.Where(v => v.VacationEnd > DateTime.Now);
```

The last one doesn't filter any future vacations.

Comment: Hmm, maybe you are right and i need just one more query to ask on oldest/newest vacation in interval....

Comment: well if all you are trying to do is find out how many vacations are in progress or have not even started yet you just need to compare on the enddate. var query = context.Vacations.Where(v => v.VacationEnd > DateTime.Now);   This will give you any vacations currently in progress as well as all future vacations because a vacation end date should always be greater than the start date.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right. For my example i need just use your first soluion. I am bit tired, so i am asking stupid question.

Thanks for help.